# read.table in Chunks - error message

Tags: r, read.table

I have a large file with 6mil rows and I'm trying to read the data in chunks for processing so I don't hit my RAM limit.  Here is my code (note temp.csv is just a dummy file with 41 records):

```
infile <- file("data/temp.csv", open="r")

headers <- as.character(read.table(infile, header = FALSE, nrows=1, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

while(length(temp <-read.table(infile, header = FALSE, nrows=10, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) > 0){
  temp <- data.table(temp)
  setnames(temp, colnames(temp), headers)
  setkey(temp, Id)
  print(temp[1, Tags])
}

print("hi")

close(infile)
```

Everything runs smoothly until the final iteration.  I get this error message:

```
Error in read.table(infile, header = FALSE, nrows = 10, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  no lines available in input
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table(infile, header = FALSE, nrows = 10, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'data/temp.csv'
```

Presumably this is because the final iteration only has 1 row of records and read.table is expect 10?

All the data is actually read in fine.  Surprisingly, even in the final iteration, `temp` still gets converted to a `data.table`.  But `print("hi")` and everything after it never gets executed.  Is there something I can do to get around this?

Thank you.

Comment: WHat happens if you simply run `fread("data/temp.csv", sep = ',')`?

Comment: @mnel Even with read.table I'm able to load the whole data set in.  The problem is I run into RAM issues during the processing phase so that' why I need to split it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah got it!

```
repeat{
  temp <-read.table(infile, header = FALSE, nrows=10, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  temp <- data.table(temp)
  setnames(temp, colnames(temp), headers)
  setkey(temp, Id)
  print(temp[1, Tags])

  if (nrow(temp) < 10) break
}

print("hi")
```

This still produces warning message but no more errors:

```
Warning message:
In read.table(infile, header = FALSE, nrows = 10, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'data/temp.csv'
```