# The Error " Reached total allocation..." when using "fread" function

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am trying to read 4Gb .txt file using "fread" function:

```
mydata<-fread("myfile.txt")
```

But after reading I get the following error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 193.8 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lapply(globals, function(name) { :
  Reached total allocation of 4095Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In lapply(globals, function(name) { :
  Reached total allocation of 4095Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Could anyone explain me what does it mean and would should I do to avoid this error, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have 30GB of RAM? You are storing the whole file in memory when you do this.

Comment: also potentially useful in such cases [Amazon EC2 for beginners](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Amazon-EC2-for-beginners).

Comment: Get more ram, somehow.

Comment: @josilber Sorry, it`s not 30Gb file but around 4GB, which is a little bigger than my memory is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages actually give you the direct cause. You are trying to read a 30Gb file into 4Gb of RAM. The expensive solution is to upgrade your machine to 32GB of RAM.

Unfortunately, R keeps the entire environment in RAM at all times.

The less expensive solution is to process the dataset in chunks.

You will find some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564689/rloops-to-process-large-datasetgbs-in-chunks) and also in [this article](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2013/12/tips-on-computing-with-big-data-in-r.html)

Comment: Sorry, it`s not 30Gb file but around 4GB, which is a little bigger than my memory is. Do you know any other fast methods of reading big files? Reading compressed files maybe?

Comment: No, they've all got be uncompressed eventually.

Comment: Yes, you need to read and process it in smaller pieces. But you also need to use `rm()` to free up memory. If you read 5 2Gb chunks without deleting any, you are still trying to get 10Gb into RAM.